# Vuex - what data should be flowing through the store?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, state-management

I understand *what* the store is and the purpose of Vuex, but now I'm thinking:

*"What do I actually put in the store?"*

The SPA I'm building handles a lot of data. Initially I was only putting in the "main" stuff. However, is that wrong? Should the `store` actually hold *all* data for the SPA? If I present data on the webpage, should that be flowing through the `store`?

Answer (score 7):

As a rule of thumb, is the data is only used by one of the component, or it is one way propagated to child, you should be okay with having that at component level.

But if data is changed and accessed by more than two components it can be put in centralised state: that is vuex.

Quoting from the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html):

> if you are building a medium-to-large-scale SPA, chances are you have
>   run into situations that make you think about how to better handle
>   state outside of your Vue components, and Vuex will be the natural
>   next step for you. There's a good quote from Dan Abramov, the author
>   of Redux:
>
> ***Flux libraries are like glasses: you’ll know when you need them.***

You can also refer [vue-hackernews](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) example, where you can see [lists](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/store/index.js#L13), [users](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/store/index.js#L12) are in vuex store, while components also have [data](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/components/ItemList.vue#L41) while are specific to only that component.

[data](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/components/ItemList.vue#L41) in component:

```
  data () {
    const data = {
      loading: false,
      transition: 'slide-up',
      displayedPage: isInitialRender ? Number(this.$store.state.route.params.page) || 1 : -1,
      displayedItems: isInitialRender ? this.$store.getters.activeItems : []
    }
    isInitialRender = false
    return data
  },
```

[state](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/store/index.js#L8) in vuex:

```
  state: {
    activeType: null,
    itemsPerPage: 20,
    items: {/* [id: number]: Item */},
    users: {/* [id: string]: User */},
    lists: {
      top: [/* number */],
      new: [],
      show: [],
      ask: [],
      job: []
    }
  },
```

Comment: "if data is changed and accessed by more than two components it can be put in centralised state" <-- That's probably a good way to think about it. 2 or more components --> it's going in the store.